# Space invaders bullet not appearing when key is pressed

Tags: javascript, function, game-development

In my space invaders game, there is a function shootAliens(); which is supposed to create a bullet and shoot it at the invaders when you press the spacebar. But that is not the case as when you press the spacebar nothing happens. There is also a shoot function in the player objects which updates the bullet position every 10ms. I am not sure exactly why the bullet is not appearing or moving.

This is the function which shoots the aliens:

```js
function shootAliens(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 32) {
    player.shoot();
  }
}
```

This is the player object:

```js
var player = {
  x: 475,
  y: 590,
  speedX: 0,
  shoot: function() {
    var b = new bullet(this.x+40);
    b.interval = setInterval(function(){
      b.update();
    },10);
  }
};
```

This is the bullet function:

```js
function bullet(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 590;
  this.interval = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    context.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
      if (this.x > enemies[i].x && this.x < enemies[i].x+45 && this.y > enemies[i].y && this.y < enemies[i].y+30) {
        score += enemies[i].score;
        updateScore();
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }

    this.y -= 10;
    context.fillStyle = "blue";
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
  }
}
```

I have called the shootAliens function in my main game loop here:

```js
function gameLoop() {
  window.addEventListener("keydown",shootAliens,event);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chameen, nice to have you here on Stackoverflow, and thanks for the good question quality. I think you should debug your javascript code. Why don't you (for the beginning) open your browser console and add some `console.log` statements to your code. Or even nicer: [add breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints). That way, you can find out where the problem is. Is the event fired? Does it pass the correct parameters to all functions? I'm sure you will find the solution yourself.